# Inline Documentation Comment Block for Typedef Enum

Tags: objective-c, enums, documentation, comments, typedef

**Problem**: How can a typedef enum in Objective-C (iOS) include Documentation Comment Blocks?

**Context:** I'm building a .Framework and need to insure that my Parser is well documented internally for 3rd Party Developers to enjoy Much More Better.   :)

**Code:**

```
/*!
 @typedef SCElementTypes
 @brief Types of Element SCParser may find and attempt to define
 @constant kCharacters Not a Tag.
 @constant kOpenTag Tag Opens
 @constant kCloseTag Tag Closes
 @constant kSingleTag Tag Is Single
 */
typedef enum SCElementTypes : NSUInteger {
    kCharacters = (1 << 0),
    kOpenTag = (1 << 1),
    kCloseTag = (1 << 2),
    kSingleTag = (1 << 3)
} SCElementTypes;
```

**Note:** I know how to make Documentation Comment Blocks work for a typedef (among many things), but not typedef enum...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like so:

```
typedef enum SCElementTypes : NSUInteger
{
    /**Character description*/
    kCharacters = (1 << 0),

    /**OpenTag description*/
    kOpenTag = (1 << 1),

    /**...*/
    kCloseTag = (1 << 2),
    kSingleTag = (1 << 3)
} SCElementTypes;
```

Comment: This is great! Totally shows up now in the Test App for the Framework. - - - For SCElementTypes, I needed to put the Documentation Comment between the final `}` and the second `SCElementTypes;`